# How to I can edit first name and last on my contact from ABAddressBook

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

How to I can edit first name and last on my contact from ABAddressBook.

I used this code to find some contacts with name.

```
+(CFArrayRef)searchContactOnDevice_fromFullName:(NSString *)FullName{
    NSString *searchName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", FullName];
    ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFStringRef nameRef = (__bridge CFStringRef) searchName;
    CFArrayRef  allSearchRecords = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressbook, nameRef);
    return allSearchRecords;
}
```

If I want to remove some contacts, I can use this code:

```
+(void)removeContactWithRecordsList:(CFArrayRef) selectedRecords_
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    if (selectedRecords_ != NULL)
    {
        int count = CFArrayGetCount(selectedRecords_);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            ABRecordRef contact = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(selectedRecords_, i);
            ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressbook, contact, nil);
        }
    }
    ABAddressBookSave(addressbook, nil);
    CFRelease(addressbook);
}
```

But, I need to edit firstName and lastName for contacts.

How to I can make it.

Answer (score 0):

This code not tested on Xcode....Its an overall idea which should work a/c to me cause I have done this long time ago...Try this...

```
//Code to edit contact programmatically...     
 ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    if (selectedRecordsCount_ != NULL)
    {           
       ABRecordRef contact = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(selectedRecordsCount_, index);
       contact.firstName = @"My new first name";
       contact.lastName= @"My New last name":
        ABAddressBookSave(addressbook, nil);
    }

    CFRelease(addressbook);
```

Here the whole idea is to fetch a ABRecordRef object (person object) and modify the same... then save the addressbook ....which will save you contact's edited information.

*Please let me know if you have anything more to help with this issue*